# Generate all permutations including abbreviations with weightages

Tags: python, python-itertools

My string -

```
name_target = "ARUN GULABRAO INDULKAR"
```

I want to generate all permutations with the original name and abbreviations and assign weightages to each -

```
[ARUNGULABRAOINDULKAR, 1]
[ARUNGINDULKAR, 0.9]
[ARUNGULABRAOI, 0.9]
[AGULABRAOINDULKAR, 0.9]
[ARUNGI, 0.8]
[AGINDULKAR, 0.8]
[AGULABRAOI, 0.8]
[ARUNINDULKARGULABRAO, 1]
[ARUNIGULABRAO, 0.9]
[ARUNINDULKARG, 0.9]
[AINDULKARGULABRAO, 0.9]
[ARUNIG, 0.8]
[AIGULABRAO, 0.8]
[AINDULKARG, 0.8]
[GULABRAOARUNINDULKAR, 1]
[GULABRAOAINDULKAR, 0.9]
[GULABRAOARUNI, 0.9]
[GARUNINDULKAR, 0.9]
[GULABRAOAI, 0.8]
[GAINDULKAR, 0.8]
[GARUNI, 0.8]
[GULABRAOINDULKARARUN, 1]
[GULABRAOIARUN, 0.9]
[GULABRAOINDULKARA, 0.9]
[GINDULKARARUN, 0.9]
[GULABRAOIA, 0.8]
[GIARUN, 0.8]
[GINDULKARA, 0.8]
[INDULKARARUNGULABRAO, 1]
[INDULKARAGULABRAO, 0.9]
[INDULKARARUNG, 0.9]
[IARUNGULABRAO, 0.9]
[INDULKARAG, 0.8]
[IAGULABRAO, 0.8]
[IARUNG, 0.8]
[INDULKARGULABRAOARUN, 1]
[INDULKARGARUN, 0.9]
[INDULKARGULABRAOA, 0.9]
[IGULABRAOARUN, 0.9]
[INDULKARGA, 0.8]
[IGARUN, 0.8]
[IGULABRAOA, 0.8]
```

Not concerned about this output data stucture, it can be anything. Weightage is `1` if no abbreviations and full names are used.

If an abbreviation is used, the weight gets decreased by 10%. For example `ARUNGINDULKAR` in the 2nd output row got `0.9` because the middle name got abbreviated. `ARUNGI`  got `0.8` because middle name and last name got abbreviated.

I have effectively used `itertools.permutations(name_target)` to generate the 1st set of permutations.

I am unable to wrap my head around how to combine the abbreviations. `name_target` can be of variable length when split by `' '`

Please ignore duplicates in the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator to build the name abbreviation combinations. `itertools.permutations` is also used to create all possible orderings of the original input names, and each of these full name combinations is passed to `get_combos`, where the abbreviation combinations is produced. A boolean flag (`True` for full name, `False` for an abbreviation) is associated with each name component generated in `get_combos`, allowing the weightage to be calculated:

```
from itertools import permutations as prmt
def get_combos(d, l, c = []):
   if d:
      yield from get_combos(d[1:], l, c+[(d[0], True)])
      if sum(not b for _, b in c) + 1 < l:
         yield from get_combos(d[1:], l, c+[(d[0][0], False)])
   else:
      yield [''.join(a for a, _ in c), 1-sum(0.1 for _, b in c if not b)]

name_target = "ARUN GULABRAO INDULKAR"
n = name_target.split()
l = len(n)
result = [i for b in prmt(n, l) for i in get_combos(b, l)]
```

Output:

```
[['ARUNGULABRAOINDULKAR', 1], ['ARUNGULABRAOI', 0.9], ['ARUNGINDULKAR', 0.9], ['ARUNGI', 0.8], ['AGULABRAOINDULKAR', 0.9], ['AGULABRAOI', 0.8], ['AGINDULKAR', 0.8], ['ARUNINDULKARGULABRAO', 1], ['ARUNINDULKARG', 0.9], ['ARUNIGULABRAO', 0.9], ['ARUNIG', 0.8], ['AINDULKARGULABRAO', 0.9], ['AINDULKARG', 0.8], ['AIGULABRAO', 0.8], ['GULABRAOARUNINDULKAR', 1], ['GULABRAOARUNI', 0.9], ['GULABRAOAINDULKAR', 0.9], ['GULABRAOAI', 0.8], ['GARUNINDULKAR', 0.9], ['GARUNI', 0.8], ['GAINDULKAR', 0.8], ['GULABRAOINDULKARARUN', 1], ['GULABRAOINDULKARA', 0.9], ['GULABRAOIARUN', 0.9], ['GULABRAOIA', 0.8], ['GINDULKARARUN', 0.9], ['GINDULKARA', 0.8], ['GIARUN', 0.8], ['INDULKARARUNGULABRAO', 1], ['INDULKARARUNG', 0.9], ['INDULKARAGULABRAO', 0.9], ['INDULKARAG', 0.8], ['IARUNGULABRAO', 0.9], ['IARUNG', 0.8], ['IAGULABRAO', 0.8], ['INDULKARGULABRAOARUN', 1], ['INDULKARGULABRAOA', 0.9], ['INDULKARGARUN', 0.9], ['INDULKARGA', 0.8], ['IGULABRAOARUN', 0.9], ['IGULABRAOA', 0.8], ['IGARUN', 0.8]]
```